# Open File Password Prompt While Closing

Tags: excel, vba, passwords, save, prompt

I have two separated workbooks with macroces: Book1 with Macro1 and Book2 with Macro2.
Macro1 is simple code to:

- hidely open Book2 (has an open password: 1111);
- write "test" in A1 Active Sheet of Book2;
- run Macro2 from Book2, which is simple MsgBox "Hello! I am an msgbox
  from Book2";
- close Book2 with saving.

```
Sub Macro1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim myWb As Workbook
Set myWb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "Book2.xlsb", True, False, , "1111")
myWb.Unprotect ("1111")


Cells(1, 1) = "test"

myWb.IsAddin = True
Application.Run "'Book2.xlsb'!Macro2"
myWb.Close savechanges:=True


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

```
Sub Macro2()
MsgBox "Hello! I am an msgbox from Book2"
End Sub
```

I emphasize that everything should be done secretly and the user should not see neither Book2 nor any flashes, etc.
But when code comes to the saving step a window pops up on the screen, which, by the way, can be ignored and the code will continue to run/execute but anyway it's a PROBLEM I want get rid of:
[password pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYdO2.jpg)

What I noticed:

- If I remove the opening password from book2, the saving will be successfull and without pop-up dialogs. But I need Book2 opening protected.
- I tried to modify code, but results are not unsatisfactory due to
  screen blinking, screenshots below:
  [OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnB7T.jpg)
  [V1-NOK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1DEP.jpg)
  [V2-NOK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX8dh.jpg)

V1: myWb.IsAddin = True is deleted/commented

```
Application.Run "'Book2.xlsb'!Macro2"
myWb.Close savechanges:=True
```

V2: ON/OFF IsAddin = True before/after Macro2 executing

```
myWb.IsAddin = True
Application.Run "'Book2.xlsb'!Macro2"
myWb.IsAddin = False
myWb.Close savechanges:=True
```

Comment: So, the workbook in discussion is protected only for opening. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: yes, Book2 is protected only for opening
<https://ibb.co/DpzVtpT>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way. It will open the workbook in a new session, will write in its first sheet and run the macro. But a macro sending a message from a non visible session/window is not the best idea. In order to see the message, please move the cursor over the Excel workbooks icons on taskbar, select the `MsgBox` window and press `OK`. A better idea would be do avoid sending messages. The code should run as you need:

```
Sub HiddenWBOpenRunMacro()
  Dim newEx As Excel.Application, myWb As Workbook
  
  Set newEx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  'Open the workbook in the newly created session:
  Set myWb = newEx.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "Book2.xlsb", , , , "1111")

  myWb.Sheets(1).cells(1, 1).Value = "Test"  'write in its first sheet
  myWb.Application.Run "'Book2.xlsb'!Macro2" 'run the macro

  myWb.Close True                            'close the workbook, saving it
  newEx.Quit                                 'quit the session
End Sub
```

If `ThisWorkbook` not in Excel `Trusted Locations` it must be added.

Comment: thanks for the answer @faneduru
*But a macro sending a message from a non visible session/window is not the best idea*

However, this works as I intended until book2 is password-protected:
 the book is secretly opened, data is written to it, and the message box is launched from it without flashes and on foreground, so, user doesn't even know about the Book2 and msgbox looks like a message from the book he's running (Book1).
I tested your code and it works as you declare: without flashes, msgbox is in another window, but I need it in the foreground.
<https://ibb.co/dkPhkyF>

Comment: UPD: one more discrepancy with your code: after pressing OK (msgbox) `SaveAs` prompt appears, Book2 not saved automatically.

Comment: @Andrei If **Book2 not saved automatically** this only means that the workbook in discussion is open in another session and **only because of that it cannot be saved**. Please, close Excel, restart your computer and try it again. If you really **need** the `MsgBox` to be seen, I think it can be done running a VBScript as last code line, but I cannot get you and I lost the enthusiasm of helping, no offence... You can be sending such a message from `ThisWorkbook`, without any problem. Why to pseudo need such a message from the other workbook? It should be only a matter of proving the macro call.

Comment: yes, you're right, the problem was that the Book2 was opened in another session,I killed all processes and the problem did not recur. As for the message box from another module, I really have to abandon this idea, and run a macro in `ThisWorkbook` as you advised, taking, if necessary, data (for message) from the Book2. @FaneDuru thank you for help. However, I would still be interested to know if my first idea has a solution.

Comment: @Andrei I do not think it will work in the way you tried, but I cannot swear. I mostly focused  on supplying a solution I already used. And you do not need to run **another** macro. You can simple use such a `MsgBox` in the macro I suggested. Like a separat line. Of course, all the necessary data can be easily collected after opening the workbook. Besides that, we here when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the solution works...

Comment: I ticked the box,I'm new here and haven't learned all the rules yet. The last thing about the code, if you do not press OK on the message box for a long time, then the window pops up <https://ibb.co/z73TPxV>

Comment: If user press Cancel on this windows: <https://ibb.co/SQ7S2W2> - get error

Comment: @Andrei This is **always** happening in any Excel automation!

Comment: @Andrei Of course, an error is raised. This is the way Excel automation works! It tries preventing that you tried an automation and your session is blocked until the automated application does its job... You should no press `Cancel`, or press `OK` after it appears...

Comment: @Andrei But why do you still use the message, as it was initially created? Why don't you place it in the code I suggested, after `newEx.Quit` line? Anyhow, the message blocks all Excel until the user presses `OK`...

Comment: Since the code you offer works well (hidden and without flashing) with a password-protected book, and mine does everything planned with a non-password-protected one, I made a sandwich:
1. Unptotect(open/unprotect/close&save).
2. Macro1(even call Macro2 msgbox).
3. Protect(open/protect/close&save).
The code is raw, but works as intended, hidden and without flashing,  launches a Macro2 message box from another book.
It is desirable to draw up the code offered by you in separate functions (Unprotect/Protect) to which to transfer values a path / the password, etc.
<https://ibb.co/Lg5C8y3>